# SugarCRM - Order contacts list by inactivity.

Tags: sugarcrm

I would like to be able to sort my contact list to retrieve the ones that has no activities since a long time in order to contact them. The contacts that are inactive for the longest time would be on top of the list.

I already know how to build custom search in Sugar, but this one seems to be to hard for me...

any advices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather do the following:

1. Create custom integer field in Contacts module
2. Add custom logic to calculate time in days from the last activity (Meetings, Calls, etc.) and update field created above
3. Create a scheduler task for this logic to let it run on daily basis and update the field
4. Add the field to ListView

You can also create so called 'non-db' custom field instead of real db field to calculate 'last_activity_date' on-the-fly. But in this case you'll probably face with sorting issues while working with ListView: trying to sort records in ListView against 'non-db' fields "blanks" all the records returned by ListView. Moreover you'll have to extend existing Contact bean and build custom queries to be able to sort records in ListView and use searchdefs filters.